# ScrollViewer scrolls back when released

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, itemscontrol, scrollviewer

When I tap and hold and move my list around, it moves, but when I no longer hold, it smoothly scrolls back to beginning of the list. How do I prevent it?

I also tried putting whole ItemsControl inside ScrollViewer - same behavior.

Without ScrollViewer ItemsControl doesn't scroll at all.

I set breakpoints to ManipulationCompleted of ItemsPresenter, ItemsControl and ScrollViewer - in all of them scroll appears in correct position where I left it, but afterwards somewhere it scrolls back.

Here's my xaml markup:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ItemsControl Name="lbDeployments" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Deployments}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DeploymentItem}" >
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                <Grid>
                    <ScrollViewer>                    
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

Please help

Comment: Also putting Grid inside ScrollViewer didn't help

Comment: ItemsControl with ScrollViewer is not virtualizing => can cause bad performance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the ScrollViewer needs a container of a fixed size to know much it can actually scroll.

You'll need to set the height of the ScrollViewer or the grid that contains it for scrollign to work properly.

Without doing this the scrollviewer thinks it can take as much space as it likes. When this is the case it doesn't need to scroll and what you see when manipulating the content directly isn't actually scrolling but just moving the content wihtin the scrollable area.

Comment: @Rico but without it how will it know how much space it can take up? A scrollable item within a Listbox is what's really bad about this.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `RowDefinitions`:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid>

    ... 
</Grid>
```

Comment: Setting it to * doesn't help, but a fixed value works. Thank you, it seems to be the direction to dig.

Comment: The parent panorama control seems to have cut it